# Customizing enumerate item label

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, enumerate

I have a list that looks like follows:

```
1 (a) Red Apple

  (b) Blue Apple

2 (a) Red Orange

  (b) Blue Orange
```

I want to say "(a) implies (b)." So I label items as follows:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate}
\item Red Apple \label{red}
\item Blue Apple \label{blue}
\end{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate}
\item Red Orange
\item Blue Orange
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

When I write

```
\ref{red} implies \ref{blue}
```

it gives 1(a) implies 1(b). How can I get rid of the number 1 in front of (a) and (b)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package you can easy customize the reference representation using the `ref` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\ref{red} implies \ref{blue}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),ref=(\alph*)]
\item Red Apple \label{red}
\item Blue Apple \label{blue}
\end{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate}
\item Red Orange
\item Blue Orange
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, with standard LaTeX you would get `1a` and `1b` and not `1(a)` and `1(b)`.

A solution without packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\theenumii{(\alph{enumii})}
\renewcommand\labelenumii{(\alph{enumii})}
\renewcommand\p@enumii{}
\renewcommand\p@enumiii{\theenumi\theenumii}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ref{red} implies \ref{blue}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate}
\item Red Apple \label{red}
\item Blue Apple \label{blue}
\end{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate}
\item Red Orange
\item Blue Orange
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```